# How to Reduce time in for loop with dict and pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timeit

I have for loop going through pandas dataframe and doing a check with two dictionary values and assigning the result in a new dataframe, total time takes around 1ms, is there a way to reduce this.

The dictionaries

```
#For Categorical data
Cat_dict = {'Color': {'orange': 0.15,'red': 0.25, 'yellow': -0.28},
            'Fruit': {'banana': 0.36, 'orange': -1.36}}

#For Numeric Data
Num_Exdict = {'Quantity': {5.0: 0.25, 10.0: 0.02, inf: -0.54},
              'Rating': {0.5: 0.65, inf: -0.43}}

Num_Indict = {'Quantity': {-inf: 0.26, 5.0: 0.05, 10.0: -0.48},
              'Rating': {-inf: 0.61, 0.5: -0.49}}

Cat_Columns = ['Color','Fruit']
Num_Columns = ['Quantity','Rating']

Actual_df = pd.DataFrame([['yellow', 'orange', '4', '0.5']], columns = ['Color', 'Fruit', 'Quantity', 'Rating'])

Actual_df['Quantity'] = Actual_df['Quantity'].astype('float32')
Actual_df['Rating'] = Actual_df['Rating'].astype('float32')
Value_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros((1, 4)),columns = ['Color', 'Fruit', 'Quantity', 'Rating'])
```

```
start1 = timeit.default_timer()

for col in Cat_Columns:
    for keys, values in Cat_dict[col].items(): 
        if Actual_df[col].values[0]== keys:
            Value_df[col] = values
            break

for col in Num_Columns:
    for (keys_in, values_in), (keys_out, values_out) in zip(Num_Indict[col].items(), Num_Exdict[col].items()): 
        if Actual_df[col].values[0] >= keys_in and Actual_df[col].values[0] < keys_out:
            Value_df[col] = values_in
            break

end1 = timeit.default_timer()
print("total_time",end1-start1)

#total_time 0.0016077000000223052
```

First for loop for categorical data in One dictionary, Second for loop for Numeric data in Two Dictionaries, Cat_columns and Num_columns is the list of names to go through, Total number of columns is 4, so total time takes is 1ms for finish this step, is there a efficient way for the loops to reduce time?

Comment: It would help if you added some sample data, and or the things you've already tried...maybe the [.lookup()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) function?

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible example (mainly some sample of data for each data structure involved)? It will be much more easy and efficient for people trying to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Added the sample data, here the time is 1ms, for the full data the time is more, I wish to reduce as much as possible